# Why I have no Gemini API starter template in my Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1, android-ide

Why I have no Gemini API starter template in my Android Studio? I tried latest Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Beta 1  Build #AI-232.10227.8.2321.11231672, built on December 18, 2023,
tried latest Hedgehog ... No template for AI (((

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcrIi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEBog.png)

No Gemini API starter template (((

My Hedgehog Version

Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708, built on November 9, 2023

Do you have Gemini API starter template in your Android Studio ?

Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Beta
Build #AI-232.10227.8.2321.11231672, built on December 18, 2023

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview
Check above link and Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Beta 2
version is only for Gemini API starter.

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/gemini-template)

> This document outlines how you can use Android Studio to build an application that implements Generative AI using the Google AI SDK. It lays out the process in three steps. Before beginning, ensure that you are running the latest preview version of Android Studio.

you should download the beta Iguana version from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview), as this feature is not shipped with the Hedgehog release :)

Comment: Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Beta 1 still the same ((( I added screen in to the question body

Comment: are you in one of the supported regions tho? https://ai.google.dev/available_regions#available_regions

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest canaries in Android Studio Jellyfish onwards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).